# update decoded field from underlying table

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, oracle11g, sql-update

I have view based on underlying table on oracle 11g. im also using Kotlin and Hibernate as ORM

view has gender as follows:

```
decode(c.xxyy,'0','Male','1','Female','Undefined') as gender,
```

And underlying table has `CHAR(1 BYTE)` as data type
i currently only have permission to select & update view on top.
But i cant seem to find datatype to put into the view.
Trying to put attribute as `String` results in error `ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here`

Also trying other datatypes like `int` or straight up `enum GENDER` will result in different error, about data types. So i think `String` is the right choice.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TVIEW", schema = "XXXX")
    class PersonBackground(

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    var id: String,

    @Column(name = "NICKNAME")
    var nickname: String?,

    @Column(name = "BIRTHPLACE")
    var birthCity: String?,

    //@Column(name = "GENDER")
    //var gender: String
    )
```

Can i somehow update the view on top? or do i have to update the underlying table?

As soon as i removed Gender from update query, the whole thing started to work, but unfortunately we need this info too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey,

Even if you feel like you should ignore best practices, and write to your view, on top of table, i'll tell you **Not to do it**

There was never any real answer to this question and all i can say after few weeks is that your life will be a lot easier, if you just follow best practices and **write to underlying table**

thank you, and sorry